# How do I create dynamically text in a movie clip [AS3]?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want click on button not text

```
btn_start.t1.text = "hello world" // not working
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? This is not clear. Use more words

Comment: I agree with @NealDavis as usual!
Edit your question please!

Answer (score 0):

Rough code... You will have to work on it but it seems easy.
You just have to set your text for each states of the SimpleButton for each states when you create it.
That's all.
Now you may embed fonts, change the style of your TextField...

```
var btn_start:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton();
addChild(btn_start);
btn_start.upState = drawUpstate(0xcc5500,"upstate");
btn_start.downState = drawDownstate(0x444444,"downstate");
btn_start.hitTestState = drawDownHitTeststate();
btn_start.overState = drawOverState(0x888888,"overtstate");
addChild(btn_start);
placeButton(btn_start,50,50);
function drawUpstate(color:int, btnLabel:String):Sprite {
    var btn_color:uint = color;
    var mc:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var textLabel:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var tf : TextField = new TextField();
    tf.textColor = 0xffffff;
    tf.text = btnLabel;
    mc.addChild(tf);
    var g:Graphics = mc.graphics;
    drawButton(g,btn_color);
    return mc;
}
function drawDownstate(color:int, btnLabel:String):Sprite {
    var btn_color:uint = color;
    var mc:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var textLabel:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var tf : TextField = new TextField();
    tf.textColor = 0xffffff;
    tf.text = btnLabel;
    mc.addChild(tf);
    var g:Graphics = mc.graphics;
    drawButton(g,btn_color);
    return mc;
};
function drawDownHitTeststate():Sprite {
    var btn_color:uint = 0x0000000;
    var mc:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var g:Graphics = mc.graphics;
    drawButton(g,btn_color);
    return mc;
};
function drawOverState(color:int, btnLabel:String):Sprite {
    var btn_color:uint = color;
    var mc:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var textLabel:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var tf : TextField = new TextField();
    tf.textColor = 0xffffff;
    tf.text = btnLabel;
    mc.addChild(tf);
    var g:Graphics = mc.graphics;
    drawButton(g,btn_color);
    return mc;
};
function drawButton(g:Graphics,color:uint) {
    g.beginFill(color,1);
    g.drawRect(0,0,100,20);
    g.endFill();
};
function placeButton(btn:SimpleButton,x:uint,y:uint):void {
    btn.x = x;
    btn.y = y;
};
```

Best regards.

Nicolas

Comment: @tasha 95 , your question is unclear but I didn't downvote it.
It seems you are new on this website.
Please, post more code and more details about your issue if you need an answer.
You may edit your question an be more specific, you'll certainly get a better answer quickly.

Comment: @tasha95 You have perhaps to embed fonts too...
But I have no idea since your question is really unclear!

Comment: And please give us feedback! @tasha95